# Missing methods in Breeze Typescript Definition File

Tags: typescript, breeze

In the latest Breeze Typescript definition file (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) there are missing methods, notably the Validator.register and the Validator.registerFactory methods.  I'm wondering - - is this intentional, for some reason?  Even though I can edit the definition files, I don't like to do it because my changes will disappear when a newer version is downloaded.  Is there any way to extend a definition file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** These are now available on Breeze v1.3.0

---

I will add these to the next version of Breeze, out later this next week.

As a side note, the most recent versions of the breeze typescript definition files can be found in the breeze zip file for each release in the 'TypeScript' dir.  We try to keep the (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) updated as well, but there can be a delay, so its best to get it directly from the latest Breeze zip ( or directly from GitHub).

And thx for pointing this out, and if you see more please repost.

Comment: Jay - to your knowledge, is there any way to extend a definition file?  And THANK YOU for your response as well as this fine piece of software.

Comment: Any reason why you chose to declare it as a class and not an interface in the definition file? see my answer for why I am asking.

Comment: It's a great idea, I hadn't realized.  I will change this as well.

Comment: Tried converting Validator to an interface; didn't work because of static methods.  Then tried creating the interface with the class implementing the interface, but you are still stuck if you need to add static methods to the class. So pulling back on this for now, until I understand the problem better.  I will still be updating the Typescript file with the latest breeze definition though.

Comment: Created two bugs you can vote on https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/917 (my preference) and https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/916

Answer (score 1):

To answer: Is there any way to extend a definition file?

No. Validator is defined as a class. Class definitions are not open ended so the following is invalid:

```
declare class Validator  {
    static messageTemplates: any;
}

declare class Validator  {
    static register: any;
}
```

Validator was defined as a class since Interfaces do not support static methods. If typescript had supported  static members on an interface then we could have done:

```
interface Validator {
    static messageTemplates: any;

    constructor (name: string, validatorFn: ValidatorFunction, context?: any);

    static bool(): Validator;
    static byte(): Validator;
    static date(): Validator;
    static duration(): Validator;
    getMessage(): string;
    static guid(): Validator;
    static int16(): Validator;
    static int32(): Validator;
    static int64(): Validator;
    static maxLength(context: { maxLength: number; }): Validator;
    static number(): Validator;
    static required(): Validator;
    static string(): Validator;
    static stringLength(context: { maxLength: number; minLength: number; }): Validator;
    validate(value: any, context?: any): ValidationError;
}
```

The you could have simply done:

```
interface Validator {
    register(); // Whatever your signature was 
 }
```

and it would have worked since interfaces are open ended. Unfortunately in the definition file it is defined as a class i.e `class Validator` which is why there is no way of extending it other than modifying the definition file.

Comment: I'm not sure that this would work because the 'register' method is a static method on the Validator class and as far as I can tell you can't add 'statics' to a TypeScript interface.

Comment: @JayTraband here's a recommendation for modeling statics using just interfaces : http://basarat.github.io/TypeScriptDeepDive/#/modellingstatics